# Returning an Array from a function is giving error - Return Argument Type uint256[2] is not implicitly convertible to expected type

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x

I am trying to create an Array and add elements to it. Once I add the elements I try to find the length of the two arrays, store the length into a fixed size array of two elements and then return it to the length function.

Following is the code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Array {
    uint[10] public fixedArr; //  fixed size array
    uint[] public dynamicArr; // dynamic size array
    
    function addTofixedArray(uint i, uint element) public {
        fixedArr[i] = element;
    }

    function addToDynamicArray(uint element) public {
        // Append to array
        // This will increase the array length by 1.
        dynamicArr.push(element);
    }

    function length() public view returns(uint[] memory) {
        //uint[] memory lengthArray = new uint[](2); This line works
        uint[2] memory lengthArray;   // This line does not work
        lengthArray[0] = fixedArr.length; 
        lengthArray[1] = dynamicArr.length;
        return lengthArray;
    }

}
```

In the above code I want to understand why I have to create an object of array using new() to return the array from the function. In other words, why the line `uint[2] memory lengthArray;`does not work.

Error -

> Return Argument Type uint256[2] is not implicitly convertible to
> expected type (type of first return variable) uint256[] memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed length arrays (e.g. `uint[2] memory`)  and dynamic length arrays (e.g. `uint[] memory`) are stored in memory differently, as the dynamic length array has to also store the length.

From the docs:

```
The length of a dynamic array is stored at the first slot of the array and followed by the array elements.
```

Due to this difference it is not possible to convert them automatically. More info is available in the Solidity docs on the internals:

- [Layout in memory](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory)
- [Layout in storage](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays)

Edit:
An alternative for your example would be the usage of a tuple as the return type:

```js
function length() public view returns(uint fixedLength, uint dynamicLength) { 
  return (fixedArr.length, dynamicArr.length); 
}
```

Comment: Does it mean that I can't pass fixed length array from a function?

Comment: you can if you define the return type as `uint[2] memory`, but then only fixed length array with a length of 2 will be accepted.

Comment: For your example you could also use a tuple as a return type (added it to the original answer)

Comment: return type as uint[2] memory solved the problem. I am pretty sure, I tried it while troubleshooting but for some reason it did not work that time. Thanks for the help.